# pygame sprite numbering and sorting

Tags: arrays, list, pygame, sprite

I currently try to create a game with pygame, after defining the sprite Enemy, Player, and Skill, I hope the function of the skill is that the Player shoots the skill to the nearest Enemy per second, how do I get the nearest Enemy position?

While I used for loop to display the Enemy sprite in range(8) randomly from the edge of the game screen, and after one Enemy gets killed, the new enemy will be displayed. But when I use for loop, how could I know which one is sprite[1] and which one is sprite[2] followingly? Is there any way to put the sprites I created in a list or something else? So as that I can analyze which one is the nearest and let the Skill track it and kill it.

The Enemy sprite class:

`

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(ayu_img, (64, 64)) # sprite elements
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect() # sprite location fixed
        self.radius = 32
        randomNum = random.randrange(1, 4) # Dice for 1 to 4 condition
        if randomNum == 1:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(-40, -32)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, HEIGHT - self.rect.height)
        elif randomNum == 2:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(WIDTH + 32, WIDTH + 40)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, HEIGHT - self.rect.height)
        elif randomNum == 2:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-40, -32)
        elif randomNum == 4:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(HEIGHT + 32, HEIGHT +40)
        self.speedx = random.randrange(1, 2)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(1, 2)

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.centerx > player.rect.centerx: # movement judge
            self.rect.centerx -= self.speedx 
        else:
            self.rect.centerx += self.speedx 
        
        if self.rect.centery > player.rect.centery:
            self.rect.centery -= self.speedy 
        else:
            self.rect.centery += self.speedy
```

`

The way I create enemy in game

`

```
for i in range(8):
    enemy = Enemy() # create entity
    all_sprites.add(enemy) # put into the sprite list
    enemies.add(enemy) # put into the enemy list
```

`

is there any way to make enemy to enemy[ i ] for i in range(8)? or someway else? I am not sure if my idea is good or there is a simplified way to do it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`pygame.sprite.Groups`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) can be iterated:

```py
for sprite in all_sprites:
    # [...]
```

of course you can [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) the sprites:

```py
for i, sprite in enumerate(all_sprites):
    # [...]
```

and you can get a list of Sprites with [`pygame.sprite.Group.sprites`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.sprites):

```py
sprite_list = all_sprites.sprites()
if len(sprite_list) > 0:
    sprite_0 = sprite_list[0]
    # [...]
```

Comment: I am not sure if my understanding is right, does `sprite_list[0]` can help me with position check and distance comparing to other same class sprites in same group?
I tried your code in my test.py and it works well, but the out put are all the same like <Enemy sprite(in 1 groups)>, does this mean I can not judge the distance between player and sprites while it's all the same?